# How to rebuild mesh in optimized way? Example inside

Tags: mesh

I've made an example house **out of blocks**. Is there any way to automatically rebuild my model into **one solid mesh** without unnececarry polygons?[image]

Comment: Maybe try dissolve faces

Comment: That didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't one.  Because you created individual blocks, even when they're joined they're still independent meshes. Tools like dissolve faces only work on completely connected meshes.

Comment: Yeah... but maybe you can recommend me another "solid" modelling style i don't know about? For me the only that convenient is to build architecture out of blocks.

Comment: Face extruding and scaling should work well for what you're after. For example, say you have a wall that is one face. Select the face in edit mode, press 'E' to extrude, then right-click so it doesn't go anywhere. Now press 'S' to scale it down, 'G' to grab and move it into place, the extrude again, into the wall this time. Voila! A pocket in the wall, all one mesh! Play with that technique for a while, I think you'll like it.